# Can I enable Salesforce DX (Dev Hub and 2GP) and still use legacy development / deploy tools?

Tags: salesforcedx

I am considering converting a client to Salesforce DX to take advantage of source-driven development and advanced tooling. I read that enabling the Dev Hub in a production org has no effect on that production org from a user experience perspective.

However, in the process of enabling the Dev Hub, I was asked to Enable Packing 2. I've read about 2GP for the last hour and it's not a trivial jump (for me, at least) to go from Change Sets / Ant-based Migration Tool to 2GP. So if it's more than I have to time to bite off at this moment, if I enable 2GP can I still use traditional development methods (ForceCode / Force.com IDE v1), Change Sets, and Salesforce Migration Tool? Or do these tools become disabled if I enable Dev Hub and 2GP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Enabling these new methods do not impact existing methods of interacting with metadata.

Source: I'm using an org with SFDX, and Packaging 2.0 enabled, but thanks to various issues with the services, I'm still working with legacy tools.

Comment: Correct. Nothing prevents you from using your existing toolset.